# objective-C ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT value

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I am currently trying to set up an nsurlconnection I almost have everything sorted however.. 
One of the things I am having to declare is a constant error code timeout value as shown below.

```
else if (error != nil && error.code == ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT)
```

My question is what value should I put into this constant value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to define it, only make sure that you're importing Foundation, like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Also, the correct constant is:

```
NSURLErrorTimedOut
```

Comment: well I tried in both .h and .m file and still getting the error **use of undeclared identifier 'ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT'**

Comment: What iOS version are you coding for? 4.3? 5.0?

Comment: should I be doing something different if I am using ios5.0?

Comment: I can't find any reference to ERROR_CODE_TIMEOUT; are you sure you don't mean NSURLErrorTimedOut, defined in FoundationErrors.h? I don't have Xcode around now so I can't test that.

Comment: I am looking though the Foundation Constants Reference in apple docs but cannot find anything related to this constant.. please help.. really struggling here.. .seems like a simple solution could be had.. I just don't know where or how to find it.

Comment: lol, sounds like we were both looking in the same are.. yes I know im working of an example i found on stack over flow and also a suggestion.. so I will try using NSURLErrorTimedOut. and see how i go i will let you know

Comment: well im not getting any errors.. but I need to check out how to use the rest of the methods that I have as I'm not getting any data back yet.. thanks very much for the help..

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad I could be of help. I'll update the solution to make it easier to find the answer for future users.